# How can I delete a Yahoo account permanently, when I cannot access it?

Tags: account-recovery, yahoo-account

I have an account of Yahoo mail.
I forgot my password and also I forgot my security question and answer for recovery.
It's so important for me to delete my account now because someone is abusing  my account.

How can I ask Yahoo to delete my account or reset my password?

I have some information about my account like :

- I know who are my Contacts
- What emails I have in my inbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact [Yahoo! Customer Care](http://help.yahoo.com/l/uk/yahoo/edit/general.html) and supply as much detail as possible regarding the problem. You can either fill in the help form or directly phone them.

If you're going to use the form, don't forget to select "My account has been hacked" under the subject part.