# Delete duplicate Yahoo e-mail account

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo-account

I have two yahoo.com e-mail accounts. I'll refer to them as `old@yahoo.com` and `new@yahoo.com`.

I'm able to login to my `new@yahoo.com` account and receive e-mails. (I recently changed the password after the recently announced data breach, though that shouldn't be relevant.)

I still have the password for the `old@yahoo.com` account. When I try to log into it via the web page, it asks for confirmation (understandable, since I haven't accessed it in several years, most likely since 2011).

> **Let's get you into your account**
>   Tell us one of the following to get started:
>
> - Yahoo Sign-In
> - Recovery phone number
> - Recovery email address

I've tried the recovery phone number and e-mail address, but both are the same as what I used for the `new@yahoo.com` account. After I enter the "account key", the only option it gives me is to login to `new@yahoo.com`. (I don't know what "Yahoo Sign-In" is supposed to be. I already gave it my `old@yahoo.com` e-mail address to get to that point.)

I also have two verification questions and answers for `old@yahoo.com`, but I haven't gotten to a place where it asks for them.

I found a "Contact us" support link on yahoo.com's web site, but it doesn't actually seem to allow me to contact anyone; it only shows me existing questions with answers that don't seem to apply in my case.

My first preference would be to access my `old@yahoo.com` account and take a look at the ancient e-mails (and then delete the account).

My second choice, still acceptable, would be to nuke the account without being able to access it.

Given the recently announced security breach, I'm a bit uncomfortable leaving the account in place. (On the other hand, given that I can't access it myself with the correct password, I doubt that a bad guy could do much with it -- and there's almost certainly nothing in the account that I care about or that could be used for nefarious purposes.)

I've tried the [link](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?locale=en_GB&y=PROD_ACCT&page=contact&actp=lorax) suggested in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/13375/22291). It only shows me links to articles about account deletion, none of which are helpful in my case.

I've also tried http://deleteyouraccount.com/, as suggested in another answer, but the web page only shows an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was never able to contact anyone at Yahoo, but I did resolve the issue. The old e-mail account has been disabled, probably some time ago. I verified this by sending a test message to the account (something I should have thought to do sooner!). It bounced with "This account has been disabled or discontinued".

I presume this means that it's no longer vulnerable to hacking -- and if it is, I'll consider it Yahoo's problem, not mine.

(I had also posted a query on forums.yahoo.net, but I never got a response.)